# JQuery - edit row function

Tags: jquery

I want to create edit row function that opens a modal when the user clicks "edit".
I have the following code that adds the row:

```
function addRow()
    {

        var fileNameIndex = $('#file').val().split('\\').pop();

        $('#sample_editable_1 tbody').append('<tr>'+
                                             '<td class="TDversion"> '+
                                             $('#version').val()+
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '<td class="TDplatform">'+
                                             '<input class = "hiddenField" type="hidden" value ="' + $('#DDLpackages option:selected').val()+ '"' + '>'+
                                             $('#DDLpackages option:selected').text()+
                                             '</td>'+
                                              '<td class="TDexpDate">'+
                                             $('#expDate').val()+
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '<td class="TDfile">'+
                                             fileNameIndex +
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '<td>'+
                                             '<input type = "button" class = "editButton" value ="edit"></input>'+
                                             '<td>'+
                                             '<a class="cancel" href="">Delete</a>'+
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '</tr>');

        $('.editButton').on('click',function(){

            $("#myModal").modal("show");

        });
    }
```

I want the opened modal contains my data filled.

Comment: Make sure you unbind the click function from .editButton everytime row is created. jQuery will bind a new click function everytime row is created which in some browsers triggers click many times.___ To pass the data first catch it before showing the modal,then fill the fields inside the modal with the data and then call modal('show')

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: when I click "edit" I want to show a modal that lets me edit my data

Comment: I persume you are using bootstrap modal. Its easy to fill the input fields with the data of the row. Just give class to data e.g. $(this).parent().find("td.TDfile") will give you TDfile of the current row which editButton is clicked.

Comment: I don't think there's a `.modal()` method in jQuery. That looks like a plugin. Have you bothered to even test that code? It looks like it was thrown together without any rudimentary knowledge of JavaScript or jQuery. Are you aware that placing script without script tags or template bars is not possible? If you ran that code you'll notice that the script portions will just appear as inert text.

Comment: you mean like this $("#version").val($(this).parent().find("td.TDfile")) ?

Comment: the code is working perfectly !!

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

string templates are so complex and harder to maintain

you should use template language

my suggestion is [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)